# How Do I Hide the Scrollbar in Command Prompt Using Only Python?

Tags: python, command-line-interface

I am making a simple project in Python for fun, and it requires Windows Command Prompt as the main user interface, and I was wondering if it was possible to hide the scroll bar with only Python, and I wouldn't know where to start.

Comment: https://www.thewindowsclub.com/disable-scroll-forward-in-command-prompt-and-powershell shows how to do it manually. You might be able to edit the file using python. See: https://superuser.com/questions/683431/where-are-the-default-settings-saved-for-the-command-prompt-defaults

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.